# Build triggering from 3rd party repository

Tags: version-control, continuous-integration, build-triggers

Say I have a project, that depends on and build with the latest commit from a repository, managed by someone else, is there a generic way to get build triggering? I am not talking about for a project that you own where you have access to the Webhooks settings but where the project is someone else's.

An example I have for this is Docker images. Where I dockerise an application, I want to have a CI system rebuild that image whenever the application's source repository is updated. I don't have control over the webhooks of the application vendor's git so cannot add a webhook, but would like a trigger when it is updated. A short delay is reasonable (it does not need to be instant).

For argument's sake, we can assume that the repo is hosted on GitHub and that the CI supports web hooks.

Is there a tool/service that does this? I don't think that there is a way provided by GitHub or any of the other large Git hosts (GitLab or BitBucket) for doing this, but if I am mistaken please let me know. All I can think is to poll the repo in some schedules job and trigger the build from that. I suspect there may be a plugin for Jenkins to do this but would like something generic and if polling can be avoided in favour of the publish/subscribe model that would be perfect.

Comment: Docker Hub has built in support for this - https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/ - do you need something else/more?

Comment: @ViktorBenei Thanks, but I am not looking to trigger when I update my `Dockerfile` or related files, but to trigger when the source of the software it dockerises updates. E.g. if I make a container for a service (that does a `git pull` in the dockerfile and builds from source) can I get a trigger for the software vendor's git repo. Hope that makes sense. Updated question to hopefully clarify.